# Is there any faster way to convert strings into their integer format in python?

Tags: python-3.7

Is there is a similar way to achieve line 3, more efficiently without using a nested loop?

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    M = sum([int(i) for i in input().split()])
```

Comment: An alternative way is to use eval (or ast.literal_eval) to parse a literal list or tuple, but I don't know if it will be any faster.

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen I forgot to add 'sum'. I'm still learning python, and I don't exactly understand what you meant. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you do this: `M = sum(ast.literal_eval(f"[{input()}]"))`, then you input e.g. `1,2,3,4,5,6`. `ast.literal_eval` will evaluate code from a string during runtime, and you will get a list. `ast` is a built-in module so you can just import it

Comment: @dr_dmk I don't believe this will be any faster though, as literal_eval's functionality is a superset of of what you do (meaning it at least to do more checks). I believe simply splitting and parsing like you do is the most reasonable method to do so in pure Python.

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen I see. Anyway thank you for trying, at-least I learned a new way of doing it.